# Good times "are" or "is"?

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. Good times **is** what keeps life going.
> 2. Good times **are** what keeps life going.

Answer (score -3):

The sentences are not correct as they have no subject. Whose life?

Which type of sentence is correct once a subject is inserted will be determined by the subject

> **are** [enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/are)
>   verb UK ​  strong /ɑːr/ weak /ər/ US ​ strong /ɑːr/ weak /ɚ/
>   ​
>   **we/you/they form of be**
>
> **is**[enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/is)
>   UK ​  strong /ɪz/ weak /z/ /s/ US ​  strong /ɪz/ weak /z/ /s/
>   ​
>   **he/she/it form of be**

If your are addressing your audience then  **Good times are what keeps** (your) **life going**. where your is presumed but not spoken

Comment: This is a terrible analysis to give a learner. We often talk about a general concept such as "life" without ascribing it to any particular individual or group. Take this sentence, for example: _Science and Buddhism agree on [what makes life happy](https://www.lionsroar.com/love-its-what-really-makes-us-happy/) and meaningful_. There's no need to say "our lives" or "your life" or "everyone's life", and there is nothing wrong with saying, "Good times keep life going" (and that sentence's subject is _good times_).

Comment: @J.R. Sorry if I posted a stupid answer. but I cannot see "Good times" as the subject. Why because whilst it may apply in the second example for me it does not work in the first. Why because I do not regard "is" as a verb and neither does the C.E.D. That is why in this posting I said there was no subject. However no doubt you are more knowledgeable than me and can correct me. P.S. your example of "Good times keep life going" works for me (do Good times keep life going). I can see that in this case Good times is the subject.

Answer (score -3):

Neither is actually correct exactly as written.

Either of these would be acceptable:

> 1. A good time **is** what **keeps** life going.
> 2. Good times **are** what **keep** life going.

Both of the verbs need to maintain subject-verb agreement.

---

Note that you can also use a singular noun phrase in the following way:

> 3. ***Having*** *good times*<sup>(singular noun phrase)</sup> **is** what **keeps** life going.

Because it's *having* that's the actual subject, it doesn't matter if it's followed by *good times* or by *a good time*—the subject itself will still be singular.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/sport/blog/2006/oct/14/mcclareneraindangerofspin: *results are what counts*; https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1994/10/20/seeking-remedies-for-congestion/e4db9649-da83-4669-b569-93a40efc4f9c/: *Jobs are what is attracting traffic*; https://abc7news.com/sports/nfl-owners-to-vote-on-whether-oakland-raiders-move-to-los-angeles/1153937/: *fans are what makes football football*; https://www.wsav.com/news/local-news/first-black-barbershop-in-pooler-celebrates-20-years/: *customers are what keeps him going* – not sure what to make of those.

Comment: @userr2684291 They're all wrong. ;) Although, people do often make subject-verb agreement mistakes like this.

Comment: @userr2684291 - I don't think those are "mistakes". Sentences like the ones you cite are often worded as if they are answering an unasked question. In other words: **Q**: What counts? **A**: _Results are what counts_. **Q**: What makes football football? **A**: Fans are what makes football football. **Q**: What is attracting traffic? **A**: _Jobs are what is attracting traffic_. **Q**: What made us prosper? **A**: _[Libertarian initiatives are what made us prosper](https://www.daytondailynews.com/news/opinion/libertarian-innovations-are-what-made-prosper/3XNR0eY2xG37NyYsGPhTYL/)_.

Comment: @J.R. Idiomatically, if I were answering those questions, I would give only the noun. **Q**: What counts? **A**: *Results.* The full version of the sentence seems unnatural to me as a reply. And if I ever *did* give the full version, I would be careful to use the correct subject-verb agreement. (**Q**: What counts? **A**: *I think that results* ***count***.) At least I would do so if I were writing it. If we're talking about actual speech, where people are frequently imprecise (myself included), that's something different.

Comment: JasonB - Yes, but if you are a journalist and no one has asked the question, you can't just say "Results," or, "Fans." Sure, a journalist could write it like this: _What makes football football? The fans._ But there is nothing wrong with the examples found by @userr2684291 – those are a valid, oft-used alternative form.

Comment: @J.R. As a journalist, you can either ask the question yourself, and then provide a noun as an answer, or you can state *fans (are what) **make** football football.* I don't see the argument that a direct statement should not be asked in the correct manner (although a incorrect manner could be used informally). I don't think anybody would think this is correct: *fans **makes** football football*. Nor would they think that *a fan (is what) **make** football football* was right. So, if *those* aren't correct, why should *fans (are what) **makes** football football* be correct?

Comment: @JasonB - I agree that the "are what" could be regarded as superfluous. However, when one opts to put the "are what" in, the verb gets changed to match with "what" (which is what my initial comment tried to explain). In other words, parse it like this: (fans are) (what makes football football). There is no need for [this headline](https://www.daytondailynews.com/news/opinion/libertarian-innovations-are-what-made-prosper/3XNR0eY2xG37NyYsGPhTYL/) to be changed to "Having libertarian initiatives is what made us prosper" – it's fine as is.

Comment: @J.R. This may be because *what* is singular by default. I can't find a reliable source on this matter (there's a single question [on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300797/) on it, but it doesn't seem very authoritative, with conflicting opinions, and there's [this](https://unsee.cc/7bb10ad2) from CGEL, which doesn't address this particular situation, but it does prompt one to think that it may not be all that simple). I'd rather that people who study the language made the decision as to its grammaticality.

Comment: @userr2684291 Right. Both *what* ***is*** and ***is*** *what* would be singular. But *what* ***are*** and ***are*** *what* would be plural. I think the real debate is if we can follow [plural] *are* with *what* and then follow that with a singular-form verb.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, that's the question, and I think there need not occur a plural override within the fused relative, as it need not occur when it functions as the subject of a clause – much less when it functions as a predicative (because in general there's no such thing as a verb–predicative agreement: *Children **are** sometimes **a menace***). The chapter in CGEL nevertheless only talks about a plural **predicative** in the matrix potentially originating a corresponding override in that clause (the verb), which in turn potentially triggers an override in the subordinate clause.